# problem selecting data for a timespan using date literals in SAS data step

Tags: sas

When I try to to use my code from 1948- 1969 it is still giving me the code from 1940-2020. Could I have assistance?

Here is my code:

```
 data want; 
    set WORK.IMPORT; 
    where date between '01jan1948'd and '31dec1969'd;  
    run;
```

Comment: When you say it is giving you from 1940-2020, is that just all of your data? Knowing this might help you with the direction to go in this problem.

Comment: The information I have in my table has 1940-2019 I am not sure why it is adding an extra year and I am not sure why it is not doing the specific dates I want.

Comment: Is your date a valid SAS date? What did you import it from? We need some examples of what your data looks like. The only reason why this wouldn't work is if `date` is not a SAS date.

Comment: It came from a spread sheet.

Comment: Check the actual values of DATE.  `proc freq data=import;tables date;format date;run;` SAS dates in that range would have values between -4,383 and 3,652.  So if your DATE variable is just the year number instead of actual date values then all of the years from 1,940 to 2,020 would be selected by your date range.

Comment: Please Add the result of  `proc contents data=WORK.IMPORT; run;` to your question.

Comment: I suspect you're checking the wrong data set - make sure to verify the WANT data set not your imported data.If your original data didn't have 2020 there's no way the code above is adding new dates to your data so something else not being shown is also happening.

Comment: If it came from a spreadsheet, there's a possibility that the spreadsheet's columns were not formatted correctly and SAS is reading the raw Excel date instead of converting it to a SAS date. This can happen from time to time in Excel. You can convert the Excel date to a SAS date by subtracting the days different between Excel and SAS starting point days (21,916 days): `sas_date = excel_date - ('01JAN1960'd+1 - '01JAN1900'd+1);` Also see: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi29/068-29.pdf